# RandomForestClassifiers sklearn apply(X)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, sklearn-pandas

Apply returns indices of leafs.

Could anyone explain which indices does it return? Related fucntion in Matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It gives you the indices of the leaf your data point is for every tree of your forest.
This is what is then used to predict the class of your point.

Comment: not very clear what you are explaining!  is it just one index per tree, i.e., the index of the leaf of a tree where it has made the decision?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the lecture found [here](https://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/), these indices must represent the *Decision Regions* of membership for each x sample belonging to X.